# Taylor series of "function of functions"

Tags: taylor-expansion

I have crossed a problem, and it took me about 3 days. I wonder how I can find the Taylor series of "function of functions".
To be explicit, I am looking for the Taylor series of

$$y(s)=f(u_1(s),u_2(s),s)$$

I think the Taylor series at t in the T neighborhood of t-T (Where T is small enough) is as follows. Am I right?

$$y(t)=y(t-T)+\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial u_1}\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial s}\right|_{s=t-T}u_1(t-T)+\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial u_2}\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial s}\right|_{s=t-T}u_2(t-T)+\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial s}\right|_{s=t-T}(t-T)+\cdots $$
I want it to become as follows:
$$y(t)=\theta_1(t) u_1(t)+\theta_2(t) u_2(t)+\theta_3(t) $$

Comment: You also need to multiply the derivatives by $T$ of course. And this is only first order, the multivariable chain rule gets messier at higher order.

Comment: @Ian would you please post the complete answer?

Comment: This is Faa di Bruno's formula, basically. 
 See the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula#Multivariate_version)

Comment: Still looking for the solution